# Minimize function via scipy with the one dependent parameter

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I need to optimize my function with 3 variables: r, poly, eps.
**Parameter poly depends on the r parameter**. r and eps are independent but have some boundaries.
How to write the constraints for the minimization function in the right way?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse
from rbf.pde.fd import weights
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree as KDT
nx   = 101
nz   = nx
dx   = 1
dz   = dx
x,z  = np.arange(0, nx)*dx, np.arange(0, nz)*dz
X, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)
grid = np.column_stack([X.ravel(), Z.ravel()])
nn = len(grid)
boundary_index = np.argwhere((grid[:,0]==x[0]) | (grid[:,0]==x[-1]) | (grid[:,1]==z[0]) | (grid[:,1]==z[-1])).ravel()
checking = np.array([True]*nn); checking[boundary_index]=False
FDM_coefs = [-4, 1, 1, 1, 1]
def weight_matrix2(x, p, r ,diffs,
                  phi='phs3',
                  order=None,
                  eps=1.0):
    neighbors = KDT(p).query_radius(x, r)
    coefficients = np.array([weights(x[i], p[neighbors[i]], diffs = diffs, phi=phi, order=order, eps=eps) for i in range(len(p))])
    return neighbors, coefficients
def loss(args):
    r, poly, Eps = args[0], args[1], args[2]
    nb, coefs = weight_matrix2(
                x=grid,
                p=grid,
                r=r,
                diffs=[(2, 0), (0, 2)],
                phi='phs4',
                order=poly,
                eps=Eps)
    a = np.array([np.sort([i]) for i in coefs[checking].copy()])
    a = np.squeeze(a)
    error = np.empty_like(a)
    error = [mse(a[i], FDM_coefs, squared=False) for i in range(len(a))]
    return np.mean(error)
initial_guess = [1, 1, 10.**(-5)]
bnds = ((1,10),(1,10),(10.**(-10), 10.**(5)))
def constraint2(args): #Return possible poly values
    r = args[0]
    n = max(np.unique([len(i) for i in KDT(grid).query_radius(grid, r)[checking==True]]))           
    mp = (np.sqrt(8*n+1)-3)//2
    return np.arange(1, mp+1)
#constraint 2 means which values poly variable can take == np.arange(1, mp+1)
con2 = {'type':'eq', 'fun':constraint2}
result = minimize(loss, initial_guess, method='SLSQP',options={'maxiter':100, 'disp':True},
                             bounds=bnds, constraints=con2)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I corrected it, now you can repeat this code sample

Comment: Your code throws an error on line 14: `NameError: name 'nn' is not defined`